# Unable to delete file with punctuation

Tags: mac-osx, filesystems

`ls -l` shows this file: `'''---'$'\n''date: '\''2020-07-27 16:59:30'\'''$'\n''title: immutable'$'\n''---'$'\n'`

I can't seem to figure out how to delete it. The normal tricks I know don't seem to work.

I'm on macOS.

Comment: Can you not delete it from Finder?

Comment: Yes. But wondering how do delete from command line

Comment: In finder, they show up as `---?date/'2020-07-27 16/58/56'?title/ immutable?---?`

Comment: Are you using a nonstandard version of `ls` (like maybe the GNU version from homebrew or something)? That quoting looks like it was added by `ls` (probably in an attempt to be helpful), and the builtin `ls` doesn't do this.

Comment: BTW, either [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) or the [Unix & Linus stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask about this.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm using gls which I believe is gnu ls. bash keep reporting it as gls, at least.